# Word for: Creator/Innovator of a Technique

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

I'm doing some creative writing, and I've run up against a bit of a stump. I'm not here to ask for input on my writing, but rather to ask for a word that describe the creator, discoverer, or innovator of a technique or dogma. Words with religious or spiritual connotations are particularly useful.

Ex. Autori, _____ of the Paths of Apotheosis, is considered widely to be the preeminent saint of the isles of Ellynta.

Comment: How about cornerstone? Although it would not apply to an innovator, but a founding member.

Answer (score 1):

I think Pioneer will be a great choice here if you want to convey that Autori was (one of) the creator(s) of a belief.

> [Pioneer](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pioneer) - someone who pioneers a new activity, invention, or process is one of the first people to do it.

Vanguard also seems to be a close fit.

> [Vanguard](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vanguard)- the leaders of any intellectual or political movement.

Also, you may be interested in [Propagator](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/propagator) who helped in widespread acceptance of the belief.

Answer (score 0):

**Trailblazer** is a fairly emotive-sounding term, especially if you want to promote the idea that the individual 'led the way' for others to follow a particular ideology, i.e.: others followed your metaphorical trail.

From Merriam-Webster:

> a person who makes, does, or discovers something new and makes it acceptable or popular

From Cambridge:

> the first person to do something or go somewhere, who shows that it is also possible for other people